# ECS curl healthcheck on a scheduled task

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ecs, health-check

I need to call some ECS service periodically.

Trying to achieve this with a scheduled ECS task.

The task definition specifies a bare alpine-curl container, that leverages the healthcheck to curl the target service:
`CMD-SHELL,curl,--request PATCH,http://some-service-address,exit 0`

The same curl from the EC2 instance or any container running on the instance, works just great.
The curl as a healthcheck on the scheduled task doesn't get to where it should.

I can see on CloudWatch that the task itself was invoked.

Help please.

Comment: Are you using Fargate? Does your container have a public IP address? I can't remember all the networking specifics in each different case but I needed to curl localhost to get a healthcheck to work.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the base image from [byrnedo/alpine-curl](https://hub.docker.com/r/byrnedo/alpine-curl/) to [curlimages/curl](https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl) solved the problem.